# Approaching a contour integral with singularities on each axis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How do I solve an integral like this using complex methods?

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\left(x^2 + 2\right)\left(x^2 + 1\right)}dx.$$

I tried using two semi circles in the upper half plane but the singularities on the real axis are troublesome for me and I'm not sure how to approach the problem

Comment: $x = e^u $ : $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u e^u}{(e^{2u} + 2)(e^{2u} + 1)} du$ ? and it is $= \displaystyle- \int_{i \pi -\infty}^{i\pi +\infty} \frac{(u-i\pi) e^u}{(e^{2u} + 2)(e^{2u} + 1)} du$ so it leaves us with 4 residues and $\int_{i \pi -\infty}^{i\pi +\infty} \frac{i\pi e^u}{(e^{2u} + 2)(e^{2u} + 1)} du$ that is easy to compute with  $\frac{1}{(z+2)(z+1)} = \frac{-1}{z+2} + \frac{1}{z+1} $

Comment: in my class we have yet to work with residues, we're only really worked with basic contour integrals over closed loops

Comment: so don't write "singularities, complex-analysis, contour-integration,  complex methods, semi-circle" ! and the poles inside the contour I wrote are simple, just reduce the contour closer to the poles, and substract them, you'll get the integral of an holomorphic function on a closed contour $\gamma$ plus $4$ simple $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-\rho} dz$ terms

Comment: semi circles won't work

Comment: integrate $f(z)=\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z^2+2)(z^2+1)}$ around a keyhole in the complex plane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use a "quasi semicircle" as an integration contour

Let's define the complex valued function

$$
f(z)=\frac{\log(z)}{(z^2+2)(z^2+1)}
$$

we choose the branch cut of log to lie on negative real axis.

We integrate $f(z)$ along a contour which consists of a line segement just above the negative real axis $l_-$, the real axis $l_+$ and a large semicircle in the upper half plane $C$. A sketch of this contour can be found at the end of the answer (branch cut in red).

Then (residue theorem)

$$
\oint f(z)dz=\underbrace{\int_C f(z)dz}_{\rightarrow0}+\underbrace{\int_{l_+} f(z)dz}_{I}+\int_{l_-}f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{i=1,2}\text{Res}(f(z),z=z_i)
$$

but $$\int_{l_-}f(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\log(|x|)+i\pi}{(x^2+2)(x^2+1)}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)+i\pi}{(x^2+2)(x^2+1)}=I+i\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+2)(x^2+1)}$$

which leads us to

> $$
> 2I=-i\pi\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+2)(x^2+1)}}_J+2\pi i\sum_{i=1,2}\text{Res}(f(z),z=z_i)
> $$

We now need (the integral is standard)

$$
J=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\text{Res}(f(z),z=i)=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\text{Res}(f(z),z=i\sqrt{2})=-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{\log(2)}{4\sqrt{2}}
$$

putting everything in the highlighted formula above this gives

> $$
> 2I=-\pi\frac{\log(2)}{2\sqrt{2}}
> $$

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! Very detailed answer

Comment: @DavidFeng you are welcome!

Comment: hey, why don't you just avoid the branch-cut by choosing it on the imaginary axis?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai most likely i was just in the mood for this paticular contour back then... ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to compute:
$$ \color{purple}{I}=I_1-I_2=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{2+x^2}\,dx $$
where the substitution $x=t\sqrt{2}$ gives
$$ I_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(t)+\log\sqrt{2}}{1+t^2}\,dt$$
and

> $$ I = \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx} -\frac{\log 2}{4\sqrt{2}}\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}}.$$

Now $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\color{blue}{\pi}$ by the residue theorem and $I_1=\color{red}{0}$ by a simple symmetry trick, i.e.the substitution $x=\frac{1}{z}$. It follows that $I=\color{purple}{\large-\frac{\pi\log 2}{4\sqrt{2}}}.$

Comment: Indeed,for $a>0$, $I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a}\log a $. since $a=1$, so $I_1=0$ ( +1)